# Facebook API Unsupported GET request for inbox thread comments?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've made a request using "me/inbox" to get the threads that are in my inbox. I can then request some of the thread objects using their ID directly, as well as being able to access the comments within some of the thread objects using "/comments" as the GraphAPI URL. However, some of the thread objects for some friends will not be returned. Instead, I get the following error:

> {
>     "error": {
>       "message": "Unsupported get request.", 
>       "type": "GraphMethodException", 
>       "code": 100
>     }
>   }

I was wondering if anyone had any idea where I might be going wrong in requesting particular threads, or if this is a Facebook issue?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It works for some thread ids but for other not. Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: I don't think I did. It may have been that there's another way of requesting the same information or something... And if you use this other way then you're guaranteed to get the Thread, will try find out now...

Comment: Made an answer based on what I've discovered. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of making a request to "me/inbox", I needed to be making a request to "me/threads".

From the "data" value that is returned, you can get a list of Thread objects which contain an "id" value. This "id" value can be used to request a specific thread. Using this method of retrieving Threads seemed to solve the issue.

Would welcome further solutions to retrieving Threads from Facebook!

Comment: Using this method works for me, but when i use an access token of a user who is not a developer of the app i got the following error: `You must be a developer of the application`!

Comment: Luciano Mammino: Maybe your application is on sandbox mode

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with fetching

https://graph.facebook.com/246252455409826

but this can be solved with putting your access_token like this

https://graph.facebook.com/246252455409826?access_token= ***********

I think it only takes the age authentication.